# SQL How to select rows that has one common column but are in the same table

Tags: sql

I've got a problem selecting quantities only for rows that has the same item id. Here is my table

```
ID |quanti| item    | pack    |
87 | "600"| 4924592 | 5042012
115| "300"| 4924710 | 5042034
116| "300"| 4924711 | 5042034
120| "200"| 4924710 | 5042036
121| "300"| 4924711 | 5042036
```

And what my output should look like is here

```
300 | 4924711
300 | 4924711
```

So I can SUM the quantities and use it in subquery.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: `having count(*) > 1`

Comment: `Select quantity, item from table where item = 4924711`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a window function to get such duplicates:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by quantity, item) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt > 1;
```

But wouldn't a simple aggregation be sufficient?  You'd only get one row with the values rather than two:

```
select quantity, item, count(*) as cnt
from t
group by quantity item
having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the second example did everything i wanted! :) It was hard to make it work in the subquery but i did it :D

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want this:

```
SELECT SUM(quantity)
       ,item
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY item
```

If `quantity` is not numeric, you may need to `CAST` it.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the DBMS you used, but conceptually like this:

```
SELECT quantity, item, sum(pack), count(1) AS cnt 
FROM table
GROUP BY 1, 2
HAVING count(1) > 1;
```

Comment: I dont know what you meant with those numbers 1, 2 but thanks for your reply it works the way like yours code :D

Comment: Here `1, 2` means first and second columns. Sometimes it's handy to use their number and not to duplicate list of select columns. Also you may use them  in `ORDER` clause.

Answer (score 0):

select * from table_name group by column_name;